# How to display Parameter Window data to a Label in VISIO

Tags: visio

I am trying to assign value to a LABEL in VISIO. But it is not working. Can you help me.

After I drag and drop my component on the right click I am giving an option "ADD STATION" this will add a LABEL to the component and after that I want to get value from the Parameter window and display it into the LABEL.

I am able to generate the LABEL on a button click I want some help to display the Value.

```
 Public Sub AddParameterToLabel(ByRef oLabel As Visio.Shape, ByRef sObjID As String, ByRef sParameterName As String, ByVal sPreText As String, ByVal bShow As Boolean)

    Dim sRowName As String = "Parameter"
    Dim iCurrentRow As Integer = oLabel.AddNamedRow(visSectionUser, sRowName, 0)

    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        Err.Clear()
        Dim iAddRow As Integer = oLabel.AddNamedRow(visSectionUser, "VisioSucks3", 0)
        oLabel.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, iAddRow, 1).RowName = sRowName
        iCurrentRow = iAddRow
    End If
    Dim ovCell As Visio.Cell = oLabel.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, iCurrentRow, visUserValue)

    Dim sParent As String = sObjID
    If (Len(sObjID) > 0) Then
        sParent = sObjID & DOT
    End If

    Dim oParam As Object.Interop.Param
    oParam = g_oObject.Param(sParent & sParameterName)
    Dim sPacked As String
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        sPacked = "|-1|1|0|||||"
    Else
        'Add parameters with the unit conversions, as specified by the current choice
        sPacked = sParameterName & "|" &
                  oParam.SigFigs & "|" &
                  oParam.MultiplierToUserUnit & "|" &
                  oParam.AdderToUserUnit & "|" &
                  "|" &
                  sPreText & "|" &
                  "|" &
                  "g" & oParam.SigFigs & "|" &
                  "User" & "|" &
                  oParam.UserUnitsString
    End If

    If Not oParam Is Nothing Then
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oParam)
        oParam = Nothing
    End If

    ovCell.FormulaU = FormatStringForVisioOrSQL(sPacked)
    oLabel.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, iCurrentRow, visUserPrompt).Result(visNoCast) = Math.Abs(CInt(bShow))
    oLabel.Cells("Actions.Action[1]").Trigger()

End Sub
```

The "ParameterName = Compressor.StationFrom" which I am getting here.
and the value StationFrom will be having is DOUBLE i.e 1.2,1.3 etc..

Comment: Before we go any further we need to know what this "my component" is and where it came from. Sounds like it could be a custom-made shape.

Comment: @Paul Herber Yes. I have created a custom SHAPE and in that shape We have Inlet and Outlet so over there I need to show the numbers in Label as 1.2,1.3 etc..